# Tendo Stream<Stream> como podemos obter a Stream que contém mais elementos na outra Stream

Tags: java, java-8, stream

Tenho 3 interfaces

```
public interface IGhOrg {
    int getId();

    String getLogin();

    String getName();

    String getLocation();

    Stream<IGhRepo> getRepos();
}

public interface IGhRepo {
    int getId();

    int getSize();

    int getWatchersCount();

    String getLanguage();

    Stream<IGhUser> getContributors();

}

public interface IGhUser {
    int getId();

    String getLogin();

    String getName();

    String getCompany();

    Stream<IGhOrg> getOrgs();
}
```

- Quero obter o IGhRepo com maior número utilizadores a contribuir
  (`Stream<IGhUser> getContributors()`)

**Assinatura do método:**

```
Optional<IGhRepo> highestContributors(Stream<IGhOrg> organizations)
```

- O que já fiz para alcançar o objetivo, mas sem sucesso:

  ```
  Optional<IGhRepo> highestContributors(Stream<IGhOrg> organizations){
      return organizations
              .flatMap(IGhOrg::getRepos)
              .max((repo1,repo2)-> (int)repo1.getContributors().count() -(int)repo2.getContributors().count() );
  }
  ```

O resultado é esta exceção:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

**NOTA:** Eu entendo que o `count()` é uma operação terminal da classe `Stream` e é por isso que me dá esta exceção.

Não consigo resolver este problema, ajudem por favor.

Obrigado.

Comment: Este problema depende muito do que a implementação dos seus métodos que retornam os `Stream`s fazem. Em especial, se o `getContributors()` está criando um `Stream` e o retornando (o que provavelmente é correto) ou se está sempre retornando um mesmo `Stream` ainda que este já tenha sido usado (o que provavelmente é errado). Assim sendo, para responder a sua pergunta, será necessário que você mostre pelo menos alguns trechos das implementações dessas interfaces.

Comment: Exatamente. É difícil falar o que está acontecendo se você não coloca a implementação aqui. Mas é mais possível que você esteja reutilizando o Stream de alguma forma.